# How to perform constraint optimization with undefined parameters in WolframAlpha?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, wolfram-alpha, constraints

I'm having trouble finding how to do a constraint optimization with undefined parameters in WolframAlpha.

For example, how do I solve a standard Cobb Douglas problem such as:
maximize $A x^a y^b$ on $p x + q y=m$ for $\{ x,y \}$?

Comment: I don't think you can without the values of $A,a,b,p,q,m$ but, if you have the values of those constants. You can use https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=895957d708a52242400f57757f81e627

Comment: Thank you for the comment Olba. Unfortunately I am looking for a tool that can help me solve with undefined parameters because in economics many optimizations are theoretical so we can analyze the sign of the results, for example. Since wolfram is such a complete language I just thought maybe there was a way to do this. Thank you nonetheless.